# Password protected form with HTML and PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm making a html form and need people to validate that they are who they say they are. How I'm planning on doing this is with a password field. From which the password will be sent to them by email. So only one password is eneugh, so no need for dozens of different passwords.

The HTML

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post">
<!--entire form here-->
<input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password" required />
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="button"/>
</form>
```

So my question is:

1. How do I select what the password is (I think in contact.php, not sure)
2. How do I process the password in contact.php

Thanks in advance!

Comment: After the form submission, you can get the value of the password like this `echo $_POST['pwd'];` What's not clear to you?

Comment: @TraianTatic what's not clear is how I select what the password is, and where I place the echo in the php. I'm quite new to php...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form sends data to the page `contact.php`
Here's what to write in `contact.php` so you'll get the value from the input:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['pwd']))
{
    //comparing the user input with the good password
    if ($_POST['pwd'] == 'THE_GOOD_PASSWORD_GOES_HERE')
    {
        echo 'Password is good';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Wrong password';
    }
}
?>
```

Replace THE_GOOD_PASSWORD_GOES_HERE with your password.

Also, please consider reading [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp)